# Using PouchDB and AngularJS + Angular Material error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB, AngularJS and Angular Material and i get error

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile
```

What the problem it could be? All dependencies are available in `index.html` and `package.json`

### app.js

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('scMainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMdIcons', 'pouchdb'])
       .config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'mainCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/app/views/main.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" })
}]);
```

This problem is disappear when i remove from `angular.module` `ngAnimate` and `ngMaterial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's works. The problem was with dependencies of angular and angular-animate. In my `package.json` was everything okay, but in the `node_module` was old versions of scripts.